# ActiveRecord has_one while preserving old records - Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, stripe-payments

I'm working on a Rails 5.2 project that integrates the Stripe Billing API (using the [stripe-ruby](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) gem). I've created a `Subscription` model and sill need to set up the association to the `Customer` model.

What I was going to do was to have `has_one :subscription` and `belongs_to :customer`, so that calling `customer.subscription` would return that customer's one and only subscription object. However, for the sake of record-keeping, I would like to keep that `has_one` functionality, but somehow be able to keep the cancelled subscription records (i.e the customer might have three previously cancelled subscription records, but calling `customer.subscription` returns `nil` unless the latest subscription record is still "active").

Any ideas what the best way of doing this would be?

One way I can think of would be to set it up as a `has_many`, and then set up a `Customer` model method (i.e: `customer.subscription`) to return the one most recent and active subscription record. Would that be the way to go?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: _"One way I can think of would be to set it up as a has_many"_ - i like your way

Comment: What is the logic for defining whether a subscription is active or cancelled?

Comment: Currently, I'm using the line `self.subscriptions.where(status: :active).last`, though I think it could be improved.. `:status` is an ENUM with a few value possibilities including `:active` and `:canceled`.

Comment: If it's an `enum` it has a scope, so `subscriptions.active.last` would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to having `has_many :subscriptions` in conjunction with `has_one :active_subscription` you could also use an [association extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
has_many :subscriptions do
  def current
    # logic for determining active subscription
  end
end
```

Doing this, `customer.subscriptions` would give you all of them, while `customer.subscriptions.current` would be the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a `has_many` relationship for `subscriptions` and then a `has_one` on `active_subscription` ordered on `created_at` timestamp of the `Subscription` model.

Just be aware that when you do this you should only use the `active_subscription` for getting the active subscription, not setting it. Just set it through the `has_many` `customer.subscriptions.build` method.